# Can't debug Samsung TV web app via command line

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I have 2 related issues:

1. for whatever reason, my Samsung TV web app will not Run or Debug from Tizen Studio (into Emulator or TV) -- it just says that it failed
2. When I try to build/package/install (or run) from the command line tools, it *says* it fails, but the app is actually installed and will run (again, same behavior in both Emulator and TV)

But my major roadblock is that I seemingly cannot get the Developer tools in Chrome to be attached to the running app. The instructions say to connect via:
TV_IP:7011
but this just returns a "can't connect" page.

There is no command line tool to *debug* an application, only one to *run* it.

Even to get my application (a non-trivial web application being ported from a server) to build in Tizen Studio required hunting down many validation steps/settings and disabling them. But I eventually was able to get a .wgt package to build--but it won't install.

When you run the app on the TV, it does start up, but hangs at a certain point after. Obviously being without any debugger or console etc. is a huge impediment.

I am completely able to build/debug a much simpler "toy" application in Tizen (again, can both Debug/Run on both Emulator and TV) so all the TV plumbing is connected. Just something about this more complex app causes Tizen to choke trying to install it, and if it thinks that failed, you can't get it to debug. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This could be related to permissions. Disable all permissions and code related to them and attempt to install the app on the emulator. Upon request SAMSUNG advised us against using the emulator, at least from SSSP5 (Tizen 3.0) onwards. There were also issues with specific emulator images versus Tizen TV project profiles.

Comment: @androticus did you ever get this to work? I've run into the same wall.

Comment: Please post full logs from the TizenSudio IDE and/or the terminal from deploying, installing, and running the application in debug mode. I work with these tools full-time but I don't have enough information from your question to provide an answer.